# jquery to click on link

Tags: jquery

I'm using the fantastic infinite scroll plugin on a site I'm building.
The problem is, because my body and html are height:100% I needed to load in posts with a 'load more' button.

However, I discovered I could use jquery to trigger the 'click' even on a button when the scroll is near the bottom, this works fine when it's applied to an element that isn't an a tag, but for some reason clicking on #next-paginav doesn't work.

It'll trigger alright if it's bound to any other part of the page that isn't a link.

Is this a feature of jquery or a bug?
And how do I trigger the event on #next-paginav, whilst it's an a tag?

```
$(function(){ 
    $(document).scroll(function (e) { 

        var intBottomMargin = 300; 


        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - intBottomMargin) {
            $("#next-paginav").click();
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: `$("#next-paginav").trigger('click');`

Comment: which is the jquery version used? and how is the click event handler registered

Comment: Try calling the DOM element's _click()_ method directly. _$("#next-paginav")[0].click()_ (I've had the same problem with anchor elements and that's how I got around it.) @ubercooluk - isn't that the same thing? _click()_ is just a shortcut to _trigger("click")_

Comment: @ubercooluk no dice, doesn't work. > arun p johny 1.8.2 nothing appears to happen when it's bound to the a tag

Comment: My assumption is you have registered the click event using  `href` attributes, this event handlers will not be fired using `.trigger()` or `.click()` method

Comment: @andy checkout this demo http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z34rv/

Comment: @nnnnnn that worked, thanks.

Another problem though, it fires so quickly it just rips every single post from the database first time you reach the bottom of the page.
Is there a way to give it a 300ms delay or something between fires?

Comment: hmm, this works  setTimeout(function(){ $("#next-paginav")[0].click(); }, 500);

Except, it'd be better if I could trigger it based on scroll of the content div instead of the entire browser.
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - intBottomMargin) {
Like, does it have to be document or can it be a div class, say .main-content?

Comment: So, this works (kind of)  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $('main-content').height() - $(window).height() - intBottomMargin) {

But it appears to sometimes fire twice.